# Firefox use the "restore last session" function on web application

Tags: php, javascript, html, firefox

I want to use the "Restore last session" function in firefox, on my own customized homepage.
I just can't find any information on how to use the function, if it is even possible.

so:

1. Is it possible to use the restore last session on a webpage?
2. if it is, how? javascript, php, html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox's feature it is not something you can script with your web page.

However you can use HTML5 storage to save the "state" of a page and restore it later, but it's  not an out-of-the-box solution. You'd have to script it all yourself.

Comment: that doesn't matter as long as i can restore the last opened tabs.

Answer (score 1):

errr.. cookies? webstorage? plus JavaScript? ring any bells? just google how they work, and you can assemble one yourself.

#### Overview

**cookies** are bite-sized pieces of data (hence "cookies". I think they are just 4KB in size), that you can store bits of info about a session. on modern browsers, there is what you call a **web storage**, specifically the localstorage. it's bigger than cookies (5MB on Chrome, 10MB on the others).

both these resources are accessible via JavaScript but only cookies are naturally seen by PHP since they are sent with the request headers. with these storage options plus a bit of JS/PHP manipulation, you can return to your "last session"

but note about security also. both storages are visible to scripts as well as debuggers. [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) treats localstorage as cookies, [chrome](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage) treats them as cache. don't put sensitive content in them. I suggest you place "markers" instead, indicators to a database record. then have a database store the real session info instead. that way, only the server knows where and what you did.

Comment: yeah but how would include the script to the curently visited page without using an iframe or stuff like that, i would have to include the update code on all open tabs or something.

Comment: if your page is AJAX powered (like say a web app), then you can use AJAX to read the stored data, send it to the server, return where the user was last and render that view. if you only have PHP, use cookies. PHP can read cookies, parse them and return the page for the user.

Comment: well.. not what i asked about. The cookie will not set itself, i need some way(javascript) to update/set the cookie, maybe every 20 sec, but this code has to be loaded on every page i visit, how do i put the code onto every page i visit?

Comment: it depends on how you set-up your site. usually, CMS like Joomla and Wordpress have plugins to embed code, which can be placed on any or all pages. For frameworks like CodeIgniter, you place it in the template that every page uses. You can also do it in PHP. For every page requested, set a cookie or a DB record before handing the browser a page. that way, you won't need JS to do it.

Comment: ummh.. do you even know what we are talking about? that is totaly not on topic...

Comment: *"how do i put the code onto every page i visit?"* - that's what you asked, i provided methods. *"do you even know what we are talking about?"* - yes, do you? you asked how to get the last session. I give you ways to store it, how to set them, how to retrieve them.

Comment: also, you can't tap into the browser to give you the "last session". you have to build a script for that yourself.

Comment: i just mean, what the has CMS's with adding a code to every page that is open?
-Firefox has the funciton to recreate the last opened websites, i just hoped that i could use this funciton

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need cookies to me. If the session has run out you can refresh it from the clients (in this case, your) cookie.

To manipulate with firefox feature through a website, you need to make a plugin for firefox, which can then listen for certain javascript commands. At least as far as I am aware. Info on the session store API can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Session_restore_API).

HTML5 webstorage could also be the way to go, as previously stated.

I dunno, I like cookies :)

Comment: Yes, a Firefox extension/plugin that imports a javascript code to the actual webpage, like the one skype uses. and then store the webpage in a cookie, that just leaves me one question. when the tab is closed the page will still be in the cookie though it was closed ?